# Basic C# about the "using" keyword

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am a beginner of C# learning.

I realize that `using` is like `import` in the C#

But then I have encountered in this situation:

```
using (con)
{
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Just curious what's this using doing in here, and what's the different without the `using (con)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This form of `using` (the [statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx), not the [directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx)) works with the [`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) interface, to reclaim unmanaged resources.

Unmanaged resources are things like database connections which cannot be simply allowed to be reclaimed by the garbage collector.  Rather, they need to be closed in an orderly fashion. When the `using` code block goes out of scope, the `Dispose()` method is called on the database connection object, closing the connection and releasing the resource.

As an example, check out the [SQLConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx) class.  Note that it inherits from the [DBConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnection.aspx) class, which in turn implements the `IDisposable` interface.  The SQLConnection object [implements the Dispose method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3cc9y48w.aspx), which closes the connection when scope leaves the `using` block.

Note that you can [abuse the `using` statement](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2008/01/16/abusing-using-statements/) and `IDisposable` for fun and profit.  ASP.NET MVC uses `using` to close HTML tags!

Answer (score 5):

`using` statement will invoke the `Dispose` method on the end of the block. The object must implement [`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/system.idisposable.aspx) interface to get it work. It works because your object `con` has a implementation for `IDisposable` and after this method it is `null`. I like to implement the `using` blocks declaring the object, for sample:

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection("connection string"))
{
    con.Open();

    using(var cmd = con.CreateCommand()) 
    {
       cmd.CommandText = "select count(*) from table";
       result = (int) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }

    con.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

> C#, through the .NET Framework common language runtime (CLR), automatically releases the memory used to store objects that are no longer required. The release of memory is non-deterministic; memory is released whenever the CLR decides to perform garbage collection. However, it is usually best to release limited resources such as file handles and network connections as quickly as possible.
>
> The using statement allows the programmer to specify when objects that use resources should release them. The object provided to the using statement must implement the IDisposable interface. This interface provides the Dispose method, which should release the object's resources.
>
> A using statement can be exited either when the end of the using statement is reached or if an exception is thrown and control leaves the statement block before the end of the statement.

The using statement forces the cleanup of resources without the developer having to explicitly dispose of them or waiting for the Garbage Collector to reclaim the resources.

Answer (score 3):

The `using` block can be applied to any .NET object that implements the `IDisposable` interface. If you attempt to apply the block against an object that does not, then you will receive a compilation error.

The `using` block will actually generate a `try-finally` block around the code within the `using` block.

The following:

```
using (con)
{
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

is equivalent to writing:

```
try
{
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
finally
{
    con.Close();
    con.Dispose();
}
```

The `using` block aids is a productivity enhancement that ensures a disposable object is properly cleaned up and, in my opinion, creates code that is easier to read and maintain.

Note: You can nest `using` blocks, like this:

```
using(con)
using(cmd)
{

}
```

The `using` statement in C# is the equivalent of the `Imports` statement in VB.NET.

Comment: Not sure you would call that 'nesting' it's rather just that the next like doesn't need brackets, like if-statements, it only applies to the next line of code.